# How to get objects using a ForeignKey field through another ForeignKey in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My **models.py** is something like this:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name="categories")

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="products")
```

As you can see, the product model does not have a direct connection to the department, it only has one through the category model. However, in my department details for **< Department X >**, I want to get all the products that have a category that has the department **< Department X >**. Is there any way to do it with one query? I don't want to use a for loop for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the double underscore notation to look up fields in related models, for example:

```
department = Department.objects.get(name='X')
products = Product.objects.filter(category__department=department)
```

Or, if you don't already have the `department` instance, you can filter by department name:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(category__department__name='X')
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
Product.objects.filter(category__department=<DepartmentX>)
```

Comment: @mohammedqudah i dont think we need to delete this, since they are not the same answer

Comment: yeh but the *<DepartmentX>* require one more line of code ;0

Comment: The question already mentions the <departmentx> thing, so I suppose we don't need to mention that in the answer, and in addition to the question is not about fetching the <DepartmentX>

Comment: @mohammedqudah it's ok to have more than one answer to a question, please don't ask users to delete their answers. In the view, there's a good chance that the department will have been fetched already, so querying `category__department=<DepartmentX>` is a good approach.

Comment: i am sorry. : )